# Proof that Distance in a Graph is a Metric

Tags: graph-theory, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that the distance function $d(u,v)$ for a graph (defined as the minimum of the lengths of $uv$ paths of a graph $G$) is a metric. Here are the properties:

> 1. $d(u,v) \geq 0$ and $d(u,v) = 0$ if and only if $u = v$.
> 2. $d(u,v) = d(v,u)$
> 3. $d(u,v) \leq d(u,w) + d(w,v)$

I am able to prove 1. easily, but I am having trouble with a few details for 2. and 3.

Attempt - 2.: Consider a minimum-length $uv$ path in $G$, $P: u=u_1, u_2, \dots , u_n = v$. Now consider a minimum length $v-u$ path $P'$. If $P' = P$, we are done. Otherwise, let $P'$ be a different path than $P$. $P'$ cannot be of a shorter length than $P$, or this would contradict the minimality of $P$ as a $uv$ path.

Where I'm getting stuck: I want to show that $P'$ cannot be longer than $P$ (and hence must be equal in length), but I'm not sure what I can use to show this. Is my proof on the right track? How can I show $P'$ cannot be longer than $P$?

Attempt - 3.: Let $u,v,w$ be vertices in $G$, and let $P$ be a $uw$ path of length $d(u,w)$. Let $P'$ be a $wv$ path of length $d(w,v)$. Then we can form a $uv$ path $S$ out of $P$ and $P'$.

Where I'm getting stuck: My hint is to find the construction of such a path described, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to show that this path exists and how to construct it.

Comment: For 2. If $uu_1u_2\cdots u_n v$ is a path from $u$ to $v$, then $v u_n u_{n-1}\cdots u_1 u$ is a path from $v$ to $u$. For 3. The concatenation of a path from $u$ to $v$ and a path from $v$ to $w$ is a path from $u$ to $w$.

Comment: A path from $u$ to $v$ is automatically a path from $v$ to $u$, just by reversing the steps.  As to $3$, well, in a connected graph you can always walk from $u$ to $w$ and then from $w$ to $v$, thereby making a path from $u$ to $v$, though generally speaking this path is not minimal.

Comment: I suspect this exercise treats each edge in a (minimal) path as contributing $1$ to the length of the path.  The important fact is that each edge is assigned a positive length, and the proposition (that we get a metric) can be generalized in that way.

Comment: where did you find that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to basics:

> A path from $u$ to $v$ in a graph $(V,E)$ (so $u,v \in V$ and $E \subseteq V \times V$ is a set of pairs) is a finite sequence $u_0,\ldots ,u_n$ (with $n \ge 0$) from $V$ such that $u_0 = u, u_n = v$ and for all $i$ such that $0 \le i < i+1 \le n$ we have $(u_i, u_{i+1}) \in E$. The length of this path is then defined to be $n$. $d(u,v)$ is then defined as the minimum of the lengths of all possible paths from $u$ to $v$ (so we need the graph to be connected to have at least one path always).

Now from this definition it's rather trivial to show that if $u_0, \ldots, u_n$ is a path from $u$ to $v$, then $u'_0,\ldots, u'_n$, where $u'_i = u_{n-i}$, so following the path in reverse order, is a valid path from $v$ to $u$. No need to construct anything. Just apply the definition.

Also if $u_0,\ldots, u_n$ is a path from $u$ to $v$ and $v_0, \ldots, v_m$ is a path from $v$ to $w$, the concatenated sequence

$$u_0,\ldots, u_n(=v=)v_0,\ldots v_m$$

is a valid path from $u$ to $w$ (and its length is $n+m$). So if the aforementioned paths are the ones witnessing $d(u,v)=n$ and $d(v,w)$ respectively, we have at least *one* path of length $d(u,v) + d(v,w)$ from $u$ to $w$ so the *smallest* path is at most that by definition. Also nothing to construct, really.

Comment: Just a little add-on to this answer, the concatenated sequence is not necessarily a path, for example in the case that $u_{n-1}=v_1$. It is certainly an $uw$-walk though, and as such it does contain an $uw$-path and the rest of the answer follows.